# awk command with multiple commands

Tags: awk

When i am trying below code getting error like -

```
+ awk '{if ($1 > 1) 
{ print "Memory utilisation is high \n Please find history of the memory utilisation below" 
sar -r|awk {print' ',,,}| column -t } 
 }'
awk: cmd. line:2: sar -r|awk {print
awk: cmd. line:2:        ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:3: sar -r|awk {print

top -M -n1 | grep "Mem" | awk '{print 0 + $7}' | awk '{ print $1 / 1024 }' | awk '{if ($1 > 1)
{ print "Memory utilisation is high \n Please find history of the memory utilisation below"
sar -r|awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}'| column -t }
 }' >>/home/shyam/utilisation.txt
```

How should i redirect two outputs to the file?

Answer (score 2):

There is usualy no need to `grep .. | awk  ..| awk`

I change `grep "Mem" | awk '{print 0 + $7}' | awk '{ print $1 / 1024 }'`

- to `awk '/Mem/ {print 0 + $7}' | awk '{ print $1 / 1024 }'`
- to `awk '/Mem/ {print 0 + $7/1024 }'`
- to `awk '/Mem/ { if ( $7 > 1024 ) ...`

I would start with

```
top -M -n1 | awk '/Mem/ {if ($7 > 1024) { 
      print "Memory utilisation is high \n" ;
      print "Please find history of the memory utilisation below\n" ;
      print " sar -r|awk \'{print $1,$2,$3,$4}\'| column -t \" } }' >>/home/shyam/utilisation.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

What does `top -M -n 1` do?  On my system, `-M` is an invalid option.  I assume you're trying to get the amount of memory in use on the system (in megabytes)?  In that case, use `free` rather than `top` - extracting data from an ncurses app like `top` is silly when there are plain-text tools like `free` to do the job.

Anyway, I'm going to use `free -m` in my example script.

Building on Archemar's work to eliminate excess grep and awk commands:

```
mem=$(free -m | awk '/Mem:/ {print $3}')

if [ "$mem" -gt 1024 ] ; then (
    echo "Memory utilisation is high"
    echo "Please find history of the memory utilisation below"
    sar -r | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' | column -t
) >>/home/shyam/utilisation.txt
fi
```

Instead of using `awk` to do all of the work, it only uses `awk` to extract the memory usage data from the output of `free -m`, and then it uses shell code to do the rest.   It runs `echo` and `sar | awk` inside a sub-shell, with the entire output of the sub-shell redirected to `utilisation.txt`

If you don't have `free` on your system and `top -M -n 1` works for you then use this as the first line:

```
mem=$(top -M -n1 | awk '/Mem/ {print $7}')
```